# TimeStamp While Printing

Tags: java

I have a scenario where there is an Arraylist of Strings (Basically English Quotes). I have generated a random no form **'0'** to **'ArrayList.size() - 1'** and printed the String associated with the index. Is there any provision to keep a time stamp while printing that particular String so that it will not repeat the same string within next 10 minutes or any particular time span ? I have a infinite loop while printing and a delay of 10 sec after each iteration.

Comment: shuffle the collection ([`Collections#shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-)) then start from index 0 then 1 etc, if the list is big enough that should do it

Comment: If we go for shuffling , it may happen that the same string will occur. Then?

Comment: @SoumyaKantiNaskar if you go with shuffle - same string cannot occur

Comment: No, if you start with `[Apple, Bee, Fruit]` and shuffle to get `[Fruit, Apple, Bee]` then use Fruit, then Apple, then Bee, you don't use the same string twice (at least if you don't have duplicates in the starting list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a simple `Quote` class that has a `string` and a `java.util.Date` object, and store an array of your `Quote` objects instead of just storing an array of strings.

Also, you could just store an array of Date objects of the same size as your string array, and use the same index from your string array to check the Date.

Whenever you print a quote, update the last used date in the class or Date array. When you go to print a new  quote, check the last time it was printed.

Check out the [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) docs for more details